# WordPress plugin for partners page

Tags: wordpress

I am searching a WordPress plugin to create partners page.

Requirements:

- Easy logo and link adding and updating
- Columns and responsiveness if possible

An example - http://www.russianamericanmedia.com/our-clients/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two plugins seem to meet your requirements (perhaps in their premium version). Note that I've not tested them:

- [WP Logo Showcase Responsive Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-logo-showcase-responsive-slider-slider/)
- [Responsive Clients Logo Gallery Plugin for WordPress – Smart Logo Showcase Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-logo-showcase-lite/)

The ['Sponsors'](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sponsors/) plugin allows you to manage the partners individually. Then you can insert them as widgets in a sidebar.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mi Logo Slider plugin.It has free and paid version

Free: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mi-logo-slider/

Paid: https://miplugins.com/plugin/mi-logo-slider/